# Geometry of the Uniform Spanning Forest: Transitions in Dimensions 4, 8, 12

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory

I will give a talk (~30 minutes) on the the work of Benjamini, Kesten, Peres and Schramm "Geometry of the Uniform Spanning Forest: Transitions in Dimensions 4, 8, 12"([arXiv:math/0107140](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0107140)). I must explain the most important findings and briefly present the proof. Short Introduction:

Let N(x, y) be the minimum number of edges outside the USF in a path joining x and y in $\mathbb{Z}^d$. The key findings are:

(1) $\max_\limits{x,y \in \mathbb{Z}^d} N(x,y) = \lfloor \frac{d-1}{4} \rfloor$ a.s.

(2) $\exists $ infinitely many disjoint simple
paths with at most $\lfloor \frac{d-1}{4} \rfloor$ edges outside the USF connecting the USF-components of x and y.

They proof the following: Restrict to the case d>4.

i) $P(\max_\limits{x,y \in \mathbb{Z}^d} N(x,y) \leq \lfloor \frac{d-1}{4} \rfloor) =1$. (main part of the paper)

ii) For every $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}^d$ and every Ball $B_{r}$ with radius r, the event, that there is a path in $\mathbb{Z}^d \setminus B_{r}$ from the component of x to the component of y with
at most $\lfloor \frac{d-1}{4} \rfloor$ edges outside F have probabilty 1.

This proofs (2) and also completes the proof for 5 ≤ d ≤ 8. (ok)

For the case d>8, they proof the following:

iii) $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{Z}^d,\forall k: P(N(x,y) \leq k) \preccurlyeq (1+|| x-y || _{\ell_{1}})^{4(k+1)-d}$

and claims this proves the lower bound for max N(x,y). (I don't understand why.
I guess it is not so complicated and I'm just missing a small step.)

Maybe someone knows this work and could explain it to me briefly or give me a hint.

Answer (score 1):

If $k=\lfloor \frac{d-1}{4}\rfloor-1$, then $4(k+1)-d<0$.  So, (iii) says that $P(N(x,y)\leq k)$ gets arbitrarily small as $\|x-y\|_{\ell_1}$ gets large.  In particular, then, the probability that $N(x,y)\leq k$ for *all* $x,y$ must be $0$.  In other words, with probability $1$, there must exist some $(x,y)$ such that $N(x,y)\geq \lfloor \frac{d-1}{4}\rfloor$.

Answer (score 1):

I rephrase the Answer from @Eric Wofsey with my own words:

Take $k:=\lfloor \frac{d-1}{4}\rfloor -1$, then $ \forall \epsilon >0 \exists x,y \in \mathbb{Z}^{d}: P(N(x,y) \leq k) \leq \epsilon$,so we can conclude $ P(\forall x,y : N(x,y) \leq k ) =0 $. It follows directly $ P(\exists x,y : N(x,y) > k ) =1$, so there are almost surely some pair (x,y), such that $N(x,y)\geq \lfloor \frac{d-1}{4}\rfloor $ . Finally $P(\max N(x,y) \geq \lfloor \frac{d-1}{4}\rfloor) =1$.

Edit because of the comment made by @Misha Lavrov

Comment: Precision in language is important: we cannot "find some pair $(x,y)$ such that $N(x,y) \ge \lfloor \frac{d-1}{4}\rfloor$ almost surely". This implies that $P(N(x,y) \le k) = 0$ for some $(x,y)$, which has not been shown. Rather, we *almost surely find* some pair $(x,y)$ such that $N(x,y) \ge \lfloor \frac{d-1}{4}\rfloor$.